# Finding a cycle in a simple Prolog graph

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, cycle

I am having trouble with this simple Prolog graph, i am trying to test for a cycle and have no idea why it isn't working. `isPath` seems to work, the problem is with `cycle` function which is supposed to check if there is a cycle on the given letter. Can anyone help?

```
path(a, b).
path(a, c).
path(a, f).
path(b, e).
path(c, d).
path(d, a).
path(d, h).
path(e, f).
path(e, g).
path(e, h).
path(f, g).
path(f, b).
path(h, g).

isPath(X, X) :-
   path(X, Y).

isPath(X, Y) :-
   path(X, Z),
   isPath(Z, Y).

cycleIt(J) :-
   isPath(J, K),
   isPath(K, J).
```

Comment: I'm supposing your `cycle/1` causes a stack overflow. `isPath/2` can cycle infinitely because it doesn't check for cycles itself. To do that you need to keep a running list of where you've been in the path and reject nodes you've been to already. Also note that your `X \= Y` doesn't have any effect since `path(X, Y)` is only try already if `X \= Y` due to the construction of your facts.

Comment: I am new to prolog, so do you mean i need to create a list like appending 2 nodes with a function , then checking this :where i have been " llist with the member function to see if they have been visited

Comment: Are the paths unidirectional or bidirectional? In other words, if you have `path(a, b)` do you want `isPath(b, a)` to be true, or no? Regardless, built into your data you have a cycle. `isPath(a, X).` will run but it will provide infinite solutions because nothing stops the cycle from continuing around and around. To stop it, you need to introduct another argument, a list, which you keep track of all the nodes you visited, and check the list before you accept a node.

Comment: yes, this path is unidirectional. I think i understand and will try implement it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use DCG !
How can you find cycles ? You need to find a node From, linked by an edge to another node Via, then from Via, you need to find a path, ending in From, and you must not have cycle during this search.
so :

```
cycle --> [X], {path(X, Y)},search(Y, X, []).

% the search is ended
search(From, To, _Visited)--> {path(From,To)}, [From,To].

% we try an another path using Via, which has not been already visited
search(From, To, Visited)--> {path(From,Via), \+member(Via, Visited)}, [From], search(Via, To, [Via|Visited]).
```

The result

```
 ?- phrase(cycle, A,[]).
A = [a, c, d, a] ;
A = [b, e, f, b] ;
A = [c, d, a, c] ;
A = [d, a, c, d] ;
A = [e, f, b, e] ;
A = [f, b, e, f] ;
false.
```